# Edit readonly javascript objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, vuejs3, vue-apollo

I have a read-only object that is returned by GraphQL (vue-apollo) query, the result which is read-only looks something like this:

```
result: {
  id: 'yh383hjjf',
  regulations: [{ title: 'Test', approved: false}]
})
```

I want to bind this to a form and be able to edit/update the values in the regulations array and save it back to the database.

at the moment when I try to edit I get the error below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: "title" is read-only
```

I tried cloning the result returned by the database using object.assign

```
//target template
const regulatoryApprovals = {
  id: null,
  regulations: [{ title: null, approved: null}]
})

regulatoryApprovals = Object.assign(regulatoryApprovals, result, {
  regulations: Object.assign(regulatoryApprovals.regulations, result.regulations)
})
```

but this didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can properly clone the result?

Comment: Please, specify what is your intention regarding `regulations`. What exactly `result` is and  what exactly you expect as the output.

Comment: Thanks. It's still unclear how regulatoryApprovals.regulations and result.regulations should be merged.

Comment: I created regulatoryApprovals as a template for cloning the result object returned from the database. Not sure if that is even needed. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's likely not needed then. What are the roles of `id: null` and `[{ title: null, approved: null}]`? `result` already contains these fields. Basically `Object.assign` does a merge, not a clone. The error occurs because you merge to readonly `regulations`. array. In order to clone, you need to merge to empty object.

Answer (score 0):

`regulatoryApprovals= Object.assign(regulatoryApprovals, ...` indicates the problem because `regulatoryApprovals` is modified with `Object.assign`, so it would need no assignment.

Read-only `regulatoryApprovals` object needs to be cloned. `regulations` is an array and won't be merged correctly with `Object.assign`, unless it's known that array elements need to be replaced. It should be:

```
regulatoryApprovals = {
  ...regulatoryApprovals,
  ...result,
  regulations: [...regulatoryApprovals.regulations, result.regulations]
}
```

Where `{ ...regulatoryApprovals, ... }` is a shortcut for `Object.assign({}, regulatoryApprovals, ...)`.